# Why Induction always does not work with Big-O?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I am currently watching ocw video courses on Algorithms and in second lecture i stuck at a point where professor proves the following statement by induction:-

**n=O(1)**

```
proof:-    

For base case    
1=O(1)    
suppose n-1 = O(1)    
=> 1+(n-1)=O(1)+O(1)     
=> n=O(1).    
hence it is proved.
```

But the professor told that we cannot induct over Big-O and the above proof is not true but why?

Comment: I am assuming that adding a link to the lecture would be useful.

Comment: @0x90 ok i am adding it

Comment: The notation `1 = O(1)` seems a bit nonsensical as `1` is a number and `O(1)` is a set.

Comment: The trick is in the confusion notation. What the "proof" actually shows is that the function f_k(x) = k, that has the constant value k for all inputs is O(1) (which is true). He then lets you confuse the set of functions f_k(x) with the function f(x)=x

Comment: @FrederickCheung  what's the difference between the two functions you mentioned?

Comment: One is a function, one is a set of functions. The trick is convincing you to think of that set as a single function

Comment: @FrederickCheung Please if you can explain me in an answer that which is function and which is set.

Comment: ... What did I just read

Answer (score 4):

You **can** induct over Big-O, but the given induction process is not correct when `n` is a variable instead of a constant.

When you write `1 = O(1)`, the interpretation would be

```
if f_1(n) = 1 for all n then f_1(n) = O(1)
```

which is correct.

Now if we define `f_a(n) = a` for all `n`, then by induction we can prove that `f_a(n) = O(1)` for all `a`, which is also correct.

But if `n` is not a constant but a variable you can't get `n = O(1)` as a result of your induction since there is no `k` such that `f_k(n) = n` for all `n`.

Comment: since Big-O is not only related to algorithm complexity, you could define `f_k(n)=k/n`. This in in O(1) and `n` is variable. An other example would be `f_k(n) = k * (1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + ... + 1/(2^n))`. It is growing with `n` and bounded by `2*k` so it is also in O(1).

Comment: @AbcAeffchen, sorry but what portion of my answer you are referring to?

Comment: sorry, could have mentioned it. I am referring to the last part. you say `n` not in O(1), if `n` is variable, but what I get from your answer is that you mean `f_a(n)` is in `O(1)` if n is variable. Or do I understand you wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Mathematical induction is a tool to prove statements parametrized by integers. It cannot be applied in this case because the statement you are studying changes half way through: you take a constant 1 as the base case, and then assume a statement about the *function* f(n)=n-1.

The proof is correct in showing that any *constant* n is in O(1), though.

Answer (score 0):

Basically in math induction is a tool, to get from a well known position a well controllable step further. This don't have to be a step like `n → n+1` or `n → 2⋅n`, but most likely it is. In most cases the problem will be, that the well controllable step is of constant size, so in Big-O it just get lost.

But in some cases you can use the Big-O just for simplification while calculating the complexity, like

```
(n+a+1)(n-2⋅b)(n2-3) = n4+O(n3)                (for constants a and b)
```

There are also cases, where you can *see* the complexity in the induction step.

**Example:**
Find the complexity of `f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2)` with n ≥ 2 and `f(0) = f(1) = 1`.
The step `n → n+1` yields

```
2⋅f(n-1) ≤ f(n+1) ≤ 2⋅f(n)
```

so basically the size doubles for a `+1`. you need `n` `+1`'s to sum up to `n`, that yields the first value doubles about `n` times. The beginning (`f(1)`) is in `O(1)` so `2n ⋅ O(1)` is in `O(2n)`.

Finally there are cases in which you can proof the complexity by induction.

**Example:**
Find the complexity of `n!`.
Proof: 1 is in `O(1)`. Suppose `(n-1)!` is in `O(1)`. Then

```
n! = n⋅(n-1)! = n * O(1) = O(n).
```

Damn, `n!` can't be in `O(1)` because `(n+1)!` had to be also in `O(1)`, but it isn't. Next try:
Suppose `(n-1)!` is in `O(nk)`.

```
n! = n⋅(n-1)! = n ⋅ O(nk) = O(nk+1)
```

Damn, failed again. If `n!` is in `O(nk)`, `(n+1)!` is supposed to be in

```
O((n+1)k) = O(nk + k⋅nk-1 + ...[smaller monomials]) = O(nk)
```

But for `k = n` this would work, since for `n!` in `O(nn)`, `(n+1)!` is supposed to be in `O((n+1)n+1)` and in fact, `n!` is in `O(nn)`, but it is not a tight upper bound. To proof a better complexity you have to use better methods than induction.

So this is more an example to disproof a complexity by using induction.

In general I would not say, that there is no complexity that can be proven by induction, but in most cases exits better ways to proof it.